# Wrapping observables within action of another observable

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, observable, retrofit2, reactivex

I just started on ReactiveX and Retrofit,
Consider following example retrofit example,

```
@GET
public Observable<ResponseType1> makeFirstCall();

@POST
public Observable<ResponseType2 makeSecondCallWithFirstResponse(@Body ResponseType1 input);
```

Is it a good idea to have observable within another action1? like below

```
makeFirstCalle().subscribe((responseType1) -> {

    makeSecondCallWithFirstResponse(responseType1).subscribe("second action goes here")

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use concatMap or flatMap?

```
makeFirstCall().concatMap(responseType1 -> makeSecondCallWithFirstResponse(responseType1))
               .subscribe(....)
```

You can keep chaining if you have additional api calls. For example

```
makeFirstCall().concatMap(responseType1 -> makeSecondCallWithFirstResponse(responseType1))
               .concatMap(responseType2 -> makeThirdCallWithSecondResponse(responseType2))
               .subscribe(....)
```

Comment: I have to more than 3 api calls, which I have to call based on the previous response. Is this the only one way? Or there are any options are there?

Comment: If you want to chain observables in the way you described, I can't see any other way of doing it. What's the problem with flatMap or concatMap?

Comment: I don't know I just asked.